# MongoDB - Sort and Skip methods not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I am getting frustrated with these two methods. According to [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.find/#example) I can find limit sort and skip something like this:

> ```
> db.collection('demo_products').find({'groupid':{$exists: false}}).sort({'_id': 1}).limit(5).toArray()
> ```
>
> But when I try it I get this error:
>
> ```
> TypeError: db.collection(...).find(...).sort is not a function
> ```

I tried something different:

> ```
> db.collection('demo_products').find({'groupid':{$exists: false}}, {limit: 5}).toArray()
> ```
>
> and this worked well until I wanted to sort and skip:
>
> ```
> db.collection('demo_products').find({'groupid':{$exists: false}}, {sort: {'_id': 1}}, {skip: 1}, {limit: 5}).toArray()
> ```

It completely disregarded sort and skip operations. I tried aggregation as well, but I couldn't find $exists operator in aggregation.
I find `.find()` method more easier to use for me, but I can't figure out how to use sort and skip correctly.

I find the documentation quite misleading since it's suppose to work, but it throws the error all the time I follow it.

Comment: What does `db.collection('demo_products').find({'groupid':{$exists: false}})` evaluate to?

Comment: can you please provide some sample json data?

Comment: `db.collection` is not a function.  did you mean `db.getCollection()`?